# "Prise" and "Prize" are a matter of locations (AmE and BrE) or they are different in meaning?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

"**Prise**" and "**Prize**" are a matter of *locations* (AmE and BrE) or they are different in meaning?

When I look at the *[Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prise)*, I see that **prise** and **Prize** are the **same** and they are just spelling differently in the US (prize) and the UK (prise).  However, when I look at the article in *Cambridge dictionary* (named ["Price or prize?"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/price-or-prize)) then I see that they are *different words  with different meanings*. 
Who can to straighten the things out?

Comment: I don’t see the point here. It is two different sets of words. Incidentally “prize” has the same spelling in both cases.

Comment: "price" and "prise" are not the same word.

Comment: @user159691 Have you read the entry that I linked to Oxford dictionary? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prise

Answer (score 4):

Meaning one:

Open with force (also pry/pried)

US: He prized the lid open
UK: He prised the lid open

Meaning two:

Prized - it was very valuable - appreciated

US: They prized his presence
UK: They prized his presence

Comment: I have never heard *prize* used for Meaning one in the US. [*pry*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pry) is normally used.

Comment: Yeah, pry is normally used. Incidentally, I'm from the U.S. and I would spell the first meaning as "prise", so it may not be a rule that is strictly followed.